# How can I shorten the bash prompt's current path to one letter per directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, prompt

I can't remember where, but I've already seen the bash prompt's current path shortened in an interesting way: every directory contained in the path (excepted the last one) is replaced by its first letter only.  For instance: `path/to/some/directory` would be shortened to `p/t/s/directory`.

How can I reproduce that behavior ?

Comment: You can't directly do this in `PS1`. You would need to set `PS1` to contain a variable (`PS1='${SHORT_PWD}\\$'`) and update that variable in `$PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil' sure you can do it directly, if you use double quote you need to backslash ```\$()``` command substitutions
 though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After playing with this for a while I got the answer you require:

Add this to your .bashrc file in your home directory, exit the terminal and renter it and you will get you prompt.

```
PS1='$(eval "sps")$ '
sps() {
   echo "$PWD" | sed -r 's|/([^/]{,2})[^/]*|/\1|g'
}
```

It uses the declared function `sps()` to evaluate the path every time the variable `PS1` which is the prompt, is displayed

ie

```
/ho/de/De/Ap/Ti$ pwd
/home/deth/Desktop/Apps/Tivo
/ho/de/De/Ap/Ti$
```

**Or...if you insist on the one letter**

```
PS1='$(eval "sps")$ '
sps() {
   echo "$PWD" | sed -r 's|/(.)[^/]*|/\1|g'
}
```

Which displays:

```
/h/d/D/A/T$ pwd
/home/deth/Desktop/Apps/Tivo
/h/d/D/A/T$
```

Comment: Thanks Meer. My prompt is actually removing the `user@pc` part. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 3):

To truncate all directory names except the last one:

```
PS1='$(eval "sps")$ '                                                                                
sps() {                                                                                              
    python -c "import sys; dirs = sys.argv[1].split('/'); print '/'.join(d[:1] for d in dirs[:-1]) + '/' + dirs[-1]" $PWD
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work when I change the directories?

Answer (score 2):

shorten all names except the last one without python:

```bsh
user:/h/u/D/C/current$
```

```bsh
sps() {
    echo `dirname $PWD` | sed -r 's|/(.)[^/]*|/\1|g'
}
PS1='\u:$$(eval "sps")/\W\$ '
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to shorten the path relative from $HOME, except the last directory:

```
sps() {
    current_path=${PWD/#$HOME/'~'}
    if [ "$current_path" = "~" ]; then
       echo $current_path
    else
       path_parent=${current_path%\/*}
       path_parent_short=`echo $path_parent | sed -r 's|/(.)[^/]*|/\1|g'`
       directory=${current_path##*\/}
       echo "$path_parent_short/$directory"
    fi
}

PS1='\u:$$(eval "sps") \$ '
```

which transforms `/home/user/workspace/ocaml/project` --> `~/w/o/project`.